# Migration from JAX-RS 1.x to 2.x (Jersey) - set QueryParams as Map?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

With Jersey 1.x you used to be able to set QueryParams as a Map in its Client API:

```
// Jersey 1.x Client API
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ....
webResource.queryParams(queryParams);
```

We are now migrating to JAX-RS 2.x and want to use its new Client API. There doesn't seem to be any possibility to use a map of queryparams in one call, it looks like you need to set every single query param in a loop:

```
// JAX-RS 2.x Client API
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ....
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
    webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), value();
    // in case of multiple keys per value, we even need to use an inner loop...
}
```

For obvious reasons, this is pretty tedious and annoying - can someone confirm that this is actually the only way to solve this with JAX-RS 2 or am I missing something?

Comment: OP you can probably accept the provided answer. There is an issue logged on the JAX-RS issue tracker as [JAX_RS_SPEX-403](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-403). I have added a new comment on the ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to do this using the standard JAX-RS 2.0 client API.